# Stopwatch running while device is off, App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have made a timer app where I can tell how much time I spent on something but I need to know how to make the timer run while the phone is hibernating or I am on a different app. 
I have tried to use a tinyDB but all that does is save the seconds on the stopwatch, it doesn't keep running.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**App Inventor** apps can't run in the background. A workaround could be to store the start time in `TinyDB`. Then after coming back to your app, calculate `current time - stored start time` and continue displaying the stopwatch.

Comment: then how woud I subtract the time when I started from the current time?

Comment: see the documentation about the [Clock](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/sensors.html#Clock), see especially the `Duration` method

Comment: trying duration gives me Pacific Coast time and a bunch of other comments, I just want the pure time.
could you show me some blocks?